# Why so much censorship on Trump's statements?

Tags: united-states, election, donald-trump, democracy, social-media

After the 2009 Iranian presidential election, in which some people opposed Mahmoud Ahmadinejad's reelection, Hillary Clinton defended U.S. efforts to ensure that the Twitter social networking service has remained available for use by Iranian protesters. She said she considered it important to keep "**that line of communication open and enabling people to share information** (see [here](https://zeroanthropology.net/all-posts/annotated-bibliography-twitter-and-the-iranian-election-protests/))."

But now, in the US Election:

US president claims fraud in election, but most of effective media   censor or tags his  comments.
Isn't it important to keep
**line of communication open and enabling people to share information** in the US?

---

Is there some law that help Trump on the issue?

Comment: Are you talking about social media platforms that have rules & restrictions regarding the spreading of misinformation? Can you show an example of what you mean?

Comment: In iran election there was 100s of  misinformation. everyday there was fake news about  people that were killed by government, some of which I personally saw was wrong (I was in northwest of Iran). but media highlighted them. After 10years i dont have evidences

Comment: I meant an example of what you mean is going on right now, not back then. Just an example of trump being censored so we can easily see exactly what you mean with "media censoring".

Comment: tv cuts his speech. some media tag his comments with statements that says Biden is President elect, or ...

Comment: i should go for now

Comment: From my perspective, this is asking three separate questions at the same time: "Why is Trump being censored?" (the question title), "Is it legal to censor Trump?" ("Is there some law that help[s] Trump..."), and "Is censoring Trump compatible with America's democratic values?" ("Isn't it important to keep [that] line of communication open..."). This site is designed to answer one question at a time, not three. I think the third question is your main question, but I am not sure.

Comment: There's a fourth question here too - "Is there any actual legal restriction on an individual's right to make statements on a digital platform?"  Which I think is the actual core of the question being asked.  In short, *is* there a legal requirement for Twitter to both allow any individual to post messages on their platform, and additional, any restriction on how they can limit, censor, or embellish their posts (with, as an example, statements calling the veracity of the post into question).

Comment: What actual evidence has been presented of voter fraud? Random videos of people making claims doesn't provide any proof. Especially since it appears that none of the people with the "evidence" and "proof" are not willing to go to proper authorities to have it investigated.

Comment: Upvoted. The premise of the question is good, but the example given about Iran was bad. I think if you remove that Iran example it would be a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some law that help Trump on the issue?

Not really. There is something called [Section 230 immunity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_230) which, to the best of my understanding--and I'm not a lawyer or anything, so I could be totally wrong--protects social media companies from liability for moderating their communities. This is generally a good protection.

However, my understanding is that Section 230 is worded in a way that favors social media companies in a way that allows them to censor people (like [what happen to the NY Post](https://nypost.com/2020/10/28/twitter-ceo-anyone-can-tweet-post-articles-after-censorship/)), and this is generally considered totally legal.

There has been some suggestions recently that Section 230 should be "[reformed](https://www.justice.gov/opa/pr/justice-department-unveils-proposed-section-230-legislation)," though [this is controversial](https://www.brookings.edu/techstream/how-section-230-reform-endangers-internet-free-speech/).

Answer (score 19):

Trump is not sharing information, he is using his position as president to spread [baseless](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/11/10/us/politics/voting-fraud.html) lies about election fraud. Twitter has no obligation to enable that.

> A Twitter spokesman said via email: “As votes are still being counted across the country, our teams continue to take enforcement action on Tweets that prematurely declare victory or contain misleading information about the election broadly,” ([CNBC](https://www.cnbc.com/2020/11/04/twitter-and-facebook-label-trump-posts-claiming-election-stolen.html))

Comment: who decides that his statements are baseless?

Comment: they can let people decide; this means election.

Comment: @user1 so far *none* of his legal challenges have changed any state results. He's only "won" cases seeking a court to order that existing rules be followed.

Comment: @user1 What actual evidence has been presented of voter fraud? Random videos of people making claims doesn't provide any proof. Especially since it appears that none of the people with the "evidence" and "proof" are not willing to go to proper authorities to have it investigated.

Comment: @user1 As usual, it's the free market. Twitter decides on Twitter, Reddit decides on Reddit, Stack Exchange decides on Stack Exchange...

Comment: @user1 That's not how facts work. You don't decide what is true via an election. Something is true if it is proven to be.

Comment: @JoeW : but what is enough evidence or not, is for a court to decide. And the biggest social media platforms were very strongly biased even before this election. If you don't believe me, try writing some pro-conservative opinion articles, even without anything egregious in them, and see for yourself how many of them will be deleted for "hate speech"... while calling for a violent marxist revolution won't be deleted.

Comment: @vsz I didn't ask about how much evidence has been shown but evidence at all? All we have seen so far are random videos and claims on the internet and no claims being made to authorities by the people making the claims. If there really was evidence of fraud wouldn't the people making those claims be going to the authorities to get it investigated? If all they are doing is making claims on the internet what are they trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JoeW : but that's not for you or me to decide, neither for the social media company. People on the other side also very often make ludicrous claims, so why don't those social media companies censor them as well? Maybe the laws are too slow to catch up for this thing called "internet", imagine what would happen if a power company turned off electricity for people having a political opinion they don't like? Now social media is impactful enough for so many people, and it gets scarier and scarier that a private company can have a huge effect on elections by selectively censoring one of the sides.

Comment: @vsz In this case was the social media's platforms decision to make. But as a whole it is our decision to make because these claims are just being made in the public sphere are are not being present to law enforcement agencies to be properly investigated. These lawsuits are already getting tossed by the courts for a lack of evidence. https://apnews.com/article/ap-explains-fail-prove-election-fraud-d0f13ae6ca370c8716706d3f7d85659e.

Comment: @vsz In other cases the claims have been recanted and the person claimed a third party wrote them. https://www.thedailybeast.com/usps-staffer-richard-hopkins-told-agents-project-veritas-penned-his-ballot-tampering-claim

Comment: @vsz Social media companies practically created the far right and are extremely tolerant of conservative nonsense. The idea that they have some sort of liberal bias is laughable. Are you really trying to say Trump (the chief LEO) has all this evidence of fraud and Twitter is shutting him down to make Biden the President?? Because blocking him from saying something on Twitter doesn't stop a court from acting...if there was absolutely any evidence of fraud whatsoever

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- : I'm not talking about this specific fraud debate, but in general. And your first sentence lacks anything even remotely close to reality. When simple folk songs are censored and removed which don't have any explicit lyrics, but sing about nature and love, by being labeled as "hate speech" just because some conservatives might use them to to further national pride, then what are we talking about? If you don't believe me, try it out yourself: start posting critical posts against the left, and watch how quickly you will be demonetized or outright banned.

Comment: @vsz *Lol*. So what's your point, that Twitter should be obligated to spread Trump's lies? It's not my fault if conservatives have a habit of posting rude nonsense that violates TOS. Maybe they should stop being hateful?

Comment: If Twitter really had a "liberal bias," why continue to let Trump tweet? Why let him spread birther nonsense? Facebook is *famous* for spreading right-wing fake news among the less-Internet-savvy.

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- : it's obvious that you're living in a bubble. Just because you might have seen the odd far-right thing here or there doesn't mean it's tolerated, it's likely it was deleted soon after you've encountered it. (or what you *think* is far-right, because from your manners it seems you'll identify moderate views as far-right too)  But if you don't believe be, try it out. Post something even moderately conservative, and you'll see it will reported and removed. And post some very hateful, inciting, far-left message, or black supremacist things, and you'll see it will stay there.

Comment: @vsz Ha, *you* should try stepping out of your bubble.

Answer (score 12):

In the US, it is legal for private entities to censor or refuse to publish statements that they disagree with. Contrary to popular belief, the First Amendment only prevents the government from engaging in censorship. Twitter's refusal to publish or flagging of some statements and not others is a decision made solely by Twitter and its executives. Everyone else can only speculate.

There has been discussion in the US Congress of passing laws regulating social media censorship, but so far, no such regulation has been introduced.

Comment: Answer might benefit from pointing out that the Iranian example cited by the OP is the U.S. objecting to the Iranian government limiting the ability of the Iranian people to access Twitter. President Trump's access to Twitter has not been limited.

Comment: @jeffronicus: Not only that, but the comparison with Iran is doubly flawed because Trump still had plenty of access to spread his side of the story, Fox New (the largest cable channel), Newsmax, OAN etc. Whereas in Iran, [almost everything press is controlled by the government](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censorship_in_Iran).

Comment: As for (Iranian) laws: "Article 500 of the penal code states: "Anyone who engages in any type of propaganda against the Islamic Republic of Iran or in support of opposition groups and associations shall be sentenced to three months to one year of imprisonment."" So, yeah, in Iran CNN and much of the liberal press would have been closed (and thrown in prison) in an analogous situation.